# Is it possible to have win32 and x64 versions of native DLL in one file?

Tags: .net, 64-bit, 32-bit, native-code

Suppose I have some code written in C++. I can produce two DLLs from the code: win32 version and x64 version.

Now I want to glue these two DLLs in one file and then load appropriate version in C# application compiled for AnyCPU.

Is it possible? If it's possible then how should I approach the task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.  The bitness of the code is indicated in the header of the DLL.  The Machine field in the [IMAGE_FILE_HEADER structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  There can be only one header.  This is never a problem in practice, you simply deploy the right file with the installer.